# Fix up the "What's Meta?" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

On the [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) page, it says:

> On other Stack Exchange sites, if you have an account on the main site, you have an account on its meta site. On Meta Stack Overflow, everyone must create a separate account.

With the new child meta, this is no longer the case. Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All set now. Factually accurate and everything.